# Assign value to column in matlab

Tags: matlab

In matlab if

`a = zeros(1,2); b= ones(2,1)` then it is wrong a+b;

but `X=zeros(2,2), X(:,1)=a` works well, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The exact answer can be found on the [Matlab site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html), right near the bottom of the page:

> **Indexing on Assignment** 
> When assigning values from one matrix to
>   another matrix, you can use any of the styles of indexing covered in
>   this section. Matrix assignment statements also have the following
>   requirement.
>
> In the assignment `A(J,K,...) = B(M,N,…)`, subscripts `J, K, M, N,` etc.
>   may be scalar, vector, or array, provided that all of the following
>   are true:
>
> - The number of subscripts specified for B, not including trailing
>     subscripts equal to 1, does not exceed ndims(B).
> - The number of
>     nonscalar subscripts specified for A equals the number of nonscalar
>     subscripts specified for B. For example, 
>    `A(5, 1:4, 1, 2) = B(5:8)`
>    is
>     valid because both sides of the equation use one nonscalar subscript.
> - The order and length of all nonscalar subscripts specified for A
>     matches the order and length of nonscalar subscripts specified for B.
>     For example, 
>    `A(1:4, 3, 3:9) = B(5:8, 1:7)` 
>   is valid because both sides
>     of the equation (ignoring the one scalar subscript 3) use a 4-element
>     subscript followed by a 7-element subscript.

When you look at your example, it follows the last point in the above: although you are assigning to `X(:,2)` which is a `2x1` column vector, and the right hand side is a `1x2` row vector, the rule "order and length of all non scalar subscripts specified for A matches the order and length of non scalar subscripts specified for B".

Note that the same is not true when you want to add two matrices - in that case, they actually need to be of exactly the same shape (so you can't add a `2x1` and a `1x2` matrix, even though both have two elements).

Answer (score 0):

With "X(:,1)=b", you are asking MATLAB to copy the values of the column vector b to the first column of X. b has two rows, and so does X. So the value assignment works.

As for "a+b", matrix-matrix addition requires exact match of dimensions.

Comment: Hi, initially,there is a mistake, I mean 'X(:,1)=a'

Comment: That also works because although a is not a column vector, it has the same number of elements as the target vector.